# How to search by year when using datetime

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, search, datetime

I have a program in Visual Studio 2008.
Everything is working except that I cannot search my `datagridview` by date.
I need to be able to type in the year and then every record that have that year will be displayed.
I used `tableadapter` to add search `buttons` that searches by name and last name but when I do the same thing with the date, it says "No value given for one or more required parameters".
I used `datetime picker` to get the value of the date.

The code that I tried was

```
SELECT        
  memberno, firstname, middlename, lastname, gender, emailadd, address, phone, datejoined
FROM
  Members
WHERE        
 (DATEPART(y, datejoined) = ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datediff` function as follows

```
  SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
```

combining it

```
 SELECT 
      memberno, firstname, middlename, lastname, gender, 
      emailadd, address, phone, datejoined 
 FROM 
     Members 
 WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(year, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', yourdate)=0;
```

### Edit 1

I you are getting the value form the textbox(year which you want to search) then you can do like this

```
 SELECT 
      memberno, firstname, middlename, lastname, gender, 
      emailadd, address, phone, datejoined 
 FROM 
     Members 
 WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(year, datejoined, textboxvalue)=0;
```

### Edit 2

```
  int Year=Int32.Prase(textbox1.text);     
  var date1 = new DateTime(Year, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6);
  var date2=new DateTime(year+1,1,1,4,5,6);

  date >= date1 and < date2
```

Comment: So where do I put the first and second code? I use tableadapter so the codes are just placed in the query builder and become a toolstrip button. I need to to be able to ask the user for a year that he/she wants to search.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. It displayed the same message "No value given for one or more required parameters". And what is the textboxvalue in the code? I just entered it as it is and it didn't work. I really really need your help on this one. thanks in advance !

Comment: what are you entering in the text box an year? like `2013` etc?

Comment: yep. it should automatically have a textbox when i add the query like what happened with the others.

Comment: you need to create a valid date from year. like if user enter `2013` then you should create it as `01-01-2013` and then pass in the query.

Comment: What if I only want the year and it doesn't matter what month and day it is?

Comment: the function will compare `year only` but it takes `date` as both the argument. So you will have to give a complete date rather than a year.

Comment: how about when user selects year 2009, it displays rows where date >= '2009.01.01 00:00' and < '2010.01.01 00:00'? How do you code it?